# Working with models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

1. I have a table (posts) with a column called 'tag' I want to be able to call a particular set of tagged posts (Sports, Arts & Entertainment, etc) so that when a user clicks on the corresponding links, they only get posts from that category.

Here is what I have tried to implement so far: (in my posts model)

```
def self.seperate_by_tag
    @tag = find(:all, :tag => ??)
end
```

I'm assuming I need to input some sort of parameter into the :tag portion in order to access a set of posts with a particular tag, however, I'm not sure how to go about doing so.

1. I also am having trouble with displaying posts in the order they are posted (i'd like them to be at the top).

   ```
   def self.find_posts
       find(:all, :order => ??) 
   end
   ```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `tag` column is just text, then it would be as simple as this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_tag, lambda {|tag_name| where :tag => tag_name }
end

# Usage:
Post.by_tag('Sports').all # => collection of posts
```

Using `scope` is covered in [this Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

---

As for your other question, as long as your `posts` table has a `created_at` column (provided with the [`timestamps` migration helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#special-helpers), then you can order them reverse-chronologically (newest first) like so:

```
Post.order('created_at DESC').all
```

`order` is covered in [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering).

---

P.S. As you might have gathered from my code, the `SomeModel.find :all, ...` syntax is officially deprecated. You should instead use `SomeModel.all`, `SomeModel.first`, etc.

Comment: Could I wrap the scope portion in a method? How do I go about calling it from the controller so that I can utilize it in my view?

Comment: `scope` creates a method (`Post.by_tag`, though you can name it whatever you want) for you. I don't see what benefit you would gain from wrapping it in another method. You call it from the controller in exactly the way I show above (under `# Usage:`), just like you call `Post.find` or, say, `@some_user.posts.where(...).first`--but in this case `@some_user.posts.by_tag('Sports')...`.